# How can I use swift 2 and swift 3 at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3

Although swift 3 is released, I don't want to update my code just yet, because a lot of the CocoaPods I used are still in swift 2. I don't know what the migrator will do to those pods. Will they remain unchanged, causing the project to not build successfully? Or will they be migrated to Swift 3 as well? I don't know!

On the other hand, I really want to try out the new syntax and other new features in Swift 3. They seem really cool!

How can I continue developing my existing projects with Swift 2, but for other projects, compile with Swift 3?

In other words, how can I choose a compiler for a project?

Comment: Just create a new project in Xcode 8. What's the problem?

Comment: And it will ask me which compiler to use? @matt I don't want all my CocoaPods' code to just break because of using the Swift 3 compiler.

Comment: If it is an old project, yes it will. Just try it?!

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. :) @matt I was kinda scared.

Comment: If you are scared you are doing it wrong. Programmers try things!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I continue developing my existing projects with Swift 2, but for other projects, compile with Swift 3?

Install both Xcode 7 (which has Swift 2) and Xcode 8 (for Swift 3) and use the `xcode-select` command line tool to switch between them.

Comment: If you just type `xcode-select` with no argument at the command line you'll get help text that shows all the options. Use the `-s` option to switch to the particular Xcode you want, like `xcode-select -s Xcode7` if `Xcode7` is the name of your copy of Xcode 7 and it's in the current directory.

Comment: I just updated Xcode. But now I can't find the `Developer` folder of Xcode7. Can you tell me where it is?

Comment: Usually when you *update* an application, the old one is replaced unless you take steps to avoid that (like renaming the app first). If that seems to be what happened you can [download Xcode 7.3.1 here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). Given matt's comment on your question, though, you might not need to if you only want to use Swift 2 with your existing projects -- try using Xcode 8 first and see if that doesn't solve your problem.